# Non-monotonous DTS in output stream... changing to 1 error

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to batch remux files to mp4, copying audio, video and subtitles streams.

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -map 0:a:m:language:por\? -map 0:a:m:language:eng\? -map 0:s:m:language:por\? -map 0:s:m:language:eng\? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:s mov_text -c:a copy -movflags faststart -f mp4 "${file%.*}"-remux.mp4
```

But I get lots of errors sometimes about timestamps and non-monotous DTS streams.

Searching online I found those 2 flags here:

```
-fflags "+genpts" -avoid_negative_ts "make_zero"
```

But they don't fix my issue. What is the best way to fix this issues and make sure audio, subtitles and video are still in sync? Looking for something safe to apply to any input file in batch processing scripts, without re-encoding

Comment: Nothing to do about those. Those messages indicate faulty timestamps in the input so ffmpeg does its best to correct them.

Comment: Is it safe to use the 2 flags I found? What about `+igndts` ?

Comment: No, genpts will generate new timestamps which will destroy original timings. avoid_negative_ts will just add a uniform offset, and not change monotonicity. igndts will also regenerate timestamps. As long as the video plays fine, I'd just ignore it.

Comment: But do you recommend using those options if I'm going to batch process thousands of files? I don't care about regenerating stuff as long it doesn't cause issues / improve stuff

Comment: It will cause issues if input is variable frame rate.